# How do you find an ethical, honest independent insurance broker in Canada?

Tags: canada, life-insurance

I live in Toronto. I hope to buy a 20-year Term Life Insurance for my (gullible) mother of age 58 to replace her Permanent Life Insurance (which I believe that the evil insurance agent exploited her to buy), but how do I find an ethical, honest independent insurance broker?

I could approach, say, Manulife Financial or Desjardins directly, but was thinking to see some quotes from an independent insurance broker too.

Comment: Realizing that they're just trying to make money too.  The definition of ethical and honest may vary between people.

Comment: Ask friends and family local to you.

Comment: Why does a 58 year old need insurance? Does she still have any dependants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you find an ethical, honest practitioner of any business?

One: Make a small transaction with them and see how they treat you. If they cheat you on something small, don't give them a chance with something big.

Two: Ask family and friends for recommendations.

Three: Get information from public sources, like web sites where people post reviews of businesses, consumer advocacy organizations, groups like the Better Business Bureau, etc. Personally I consider all these of questionable value as you're asking one stranger to advise you on the reliability of another stranger, but better than nothing.